# Read more / less code but it doesn't change properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

After doing some research I came to this code shown below. If you try the code yourself you notice the variable is used for every div with a button and text (the whole site). I tried several other codes but I like the slideDown/Up feature.

```js
var status = "less"
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function() {
  if (status == "less") {
    $(this).parent().children(".toggle-text").slideDown();
    status = "more";
  } else if (status == "more") {
    $(this).parent().children(".toggle-text").slideUp();
    status = "less";
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle-text-button {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 25%;
  text-align: middle;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="toggle-text-button">Title</button>
  <div class="uk-text-justify toggle-text" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 2px;">
    <p>The text that is hidden.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="toggle-text-button">Title Two</button>
  <div class="uk-text-justify toggle-text" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 2px;">
    <p>The text that is hidden two.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If somebody knows how I can rearrange this code to make it work for every different div that would be fantastic.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"to make it work for every different div "*? It already works with multiple `<div>`s

Comment: Hi you can also try accordion of bootstrap , To know how it works check out  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `status` is "global", it's not unique for your toggle texts. There are various methods of doing this. The easiest is to check, if your `.toggle-text` class element is visible or not, and slide up/down accordingly.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function() {
  var toggleText = $(this).parent().children(".toggle-text");
  if (toggleText.is(':visible')) { // when toggleText is visible
    toggleText.slideUp();
  } else { // when it's not visible
    toggleText.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle-text-button {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 25%;
  text-align: middle;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: verdana, geneva;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="toggle-text-button">Title</button>
  <div class="uk-text-justify toggle-text" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 2px;">
    <p>The text that is hidden.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="toggle-text-button">Title Two</button>
  <div class="uk-text-justify toggle-text" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 2px;">
    <p>The text that is hidden two.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect! I was trying to make something like this but I didn't know how to code it properly. Thank you!